# when npm i imagemin say itself not install?WARN img-loader@3.0.0 requires a peer of imagemin@^5.0.0 but none is installed

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04, npm-install, laravel-echo, imagemin

npm -v
6.4.1
nvm --version
0.33.11

when I install laravel-echo (in ubuntu16.04)

```
npm i --save socket.io-client
```

I got the error warning

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN img-loader@3.0.0 requires a peer of imagemin@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ socket.io-client@2.1.1
added 26 packages from 21 contributors and audited 11731 packages in 35.934s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

So I continuce to install them

```
npm i imagemin
```

But I got the itself missing error?

```
I want to install the imagemin but it says itself missing?
    npm WARN img-loader@3.0.0 requires a peer of imagemin@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

    + imagemin@6.0.0
    updated 1 package and audited 12680 packages in 30.571s
    found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I also try

```
$npm install -g npm-install-peers

$npm-install-peers
```

shows

```
This package doesn't seem to have any peerDependencies
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

npm install imagemin@^5.0.0

fixed it for me.